# Getting hourly info from weather API

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to access hourly info from a weather API.
The problem is its not quite working for me, and I am not 100% sure of how to gain access to the information.

This is the site I am working with, and the page on the hourly info.
http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/hourly&MR=1
I have a strong feeling it has to do with the way the access to variables...

This is my code:

```
<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              $.ajax({

                  url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/6368023a57d122c7/geolookup/conditions/q/DominicanRepublic/Barahona.json",
                  dataType : "jsonp",
                  success : function(parsed_json) {

                      //get the hourly info --  cant get hourly to work...
                      var month = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['FCTTIME']['mon_padded'];
                      var day = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['FCTTIME']['mday_padded'];
                      var year = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['FCTTIME']['year'];
                      var time = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['FCTTIME']['civil'];
                      var updated = month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + time;


                      var weather = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['condition'];
                      var temp = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['temp']['metric'];
                      var humid = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['humidity'];

                      var wind_direction = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['wdir']['dir'];
                      var wind_speed = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']['wspd']['metric'];

                      var wind_string = wind_direction + " " + wind_speed + " Km/h";

                      document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = weather;
                      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = temp;
                      document.getElementById("hum").innerHTML = humid;
                      document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = wind_string;        




                  }
              });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: What does "not quite working for me" mean? What errors are you getting? What's happening?

Comment: @j08691 no errors, and unfortunately absolutely nothing is happening. As in theres no information showing up from the API. I tried a different approach to get the info, which isnt updated hourly and it worked. Somehow this doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to watch the request go out and see if its returning any codes?

Comment: I have not. Good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the JSON file from that URL you will see that it does not contain "hourly_forecast" or "FCTTIME".

**EDIT:**

Open up the JSON file that you are downloading and look at what fields it is sending back to you.  JQuery already does the hard part and parses it into an object model.  Also, the javascript debuggers in Chrome is great at showing you the JSON object model.  You can just set a breakpoint at the beginning of the "success" function and use the "Local Variables" window to explore the JSON object.

Here's your code after I updated it to use the correct field names from the JSON file...

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/6368023a57d122c7/geolookup/conditions/q/DominicanRepublic/Barahona.json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (parsed_json) {
            var current_observation = parsed_json.current_observation;

            var lastUpdated = current_observation.observation_time;

            var weather = current_observation.weather;
            var temp = current_observation.temp_c;
            var humid = current_observation.relative_humidity;

            var wind_direction = current_observation.wind_dir;
            var wind_speed = current_observation.wind_kph;

            var wind_string = wind_direction + " " + wind_speed + " Km/h";

            alert("Weather: " + weather + "\n"
                + "Temp: " + temp + "\n"
                + "Humidity: " + humid + "\n"
                + "Wind: " + wind_string + "\n"
                + lastUpdated
                );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: any suggestions of how to access the hourly_forcast? I am really unfamiliar with working with these type of API's

Comment: Perhaps you can help me out then. Using this url instead "http://api.wunderground.com/api/6368023a57d122c7/hourly/q/DominicanRepublic/Barahona.json"  How would you get the info from that?

Comment: Nevermind, scratch that last comment. Thank you, it was very helpful.